# use variable from js file into another js file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am doing an autofill extension for chrome. I made the html file where user put his information and i want that these information will be saved, because i need to use that information as a variable from a js file.
This is the html popup:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="simple-form">
      <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="full_name" placeholder="Write here your full name"><br><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Write here your email"><br><br>
        <input id="save" type="button" value="Salva">
      </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scriptExport.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the js file:

```
const button = document.getElementById('save');

button.addEventListener('click', updateButton);

function updateButton() {
  if (button.value === 'Save') {
    button.value = 'Done';
    var full_name_E = document.getElementById('full_name').value;
    var email_E = document.getElementById('email').value;
}
  else {
    button.value = 'Save';
  }
}
```

I need to load full_name_E and email_E in another js file that is the autofiller.
I tried with import and export but it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that `full_name_E` and `email_E` are only available in the local scope of the function `updateButton`. To make the available at the global scope, initialize them at the top of your code:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('save');
var full_name_E;
var email_E;

button.addEventListener('click', updateButton);

function updateButton() {
  if (button.value === 'Save') {
    button.value = 'Done';
    full_name_E = document.getElementById('full_name').value;
    email_E = document.getElementById('email').value;
}
  else {
    button.value = 'Save';
  }
}
```

If you want to learn more about this topic:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope
- https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Also you can pass these variable in a function which you can define in your other js file.